# Somando 3 inputs

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho um input que é obrigatório com mask de moeda mas o usuário pode inserir mais 2 inputs. Não estou conseguindo fazer esse cálculo, principalmente quando não são usados os 3 inputs de valores.

O input dos valores só aparecem se o usuário selecionar algo no select.

Seguem os códigos:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
        <label>Cirurgia 1<span>*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="cirurgia" required data-validation-required-message="Escolha a cirurgia." multiple title="Selecione a Cirurgia">
            <optgroup data-max-options="1">
                <option>Abdominoplastia </option>
                <option>Blefaroplastia </option>
                <option>Dermolipectomia </option>
                <option>Implante Capilar </option>
                <option>Lipoaspiração </option>
                <option>Lipoescultura </option>
                <option>Lifting </option>
                <option>Mastopexia </option>
                <option>Mamoplastia de Aumento </option>
                <option>Mamoplastia Redutora </option>
                <option>Rinoplastia </option>
                <option>Rinoseptoplastia </option>
                <option>Outros </option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row control-group valorc1">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
        <label id="namec1"><span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorc1" name="data[valorc1]" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o valor." autocomplete="off">
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esse código se repete mais 2x mudando obviamente os ids para 2 e 3.

Abaixo o resultado onde deveria aparecer o calculo:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
        <label>Valor Total da Cirurgia<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valor_total" name="data[valor_cirurgia]" readonly="readonly">
        <!-- <p id="valor_total">0,00</p> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Agora o jquery:

```
function calculaSoma(){
        var valor1 = $('input[name=data\\[valorc1\\]]');
        var valor2 = $('input[name=data\\[valorc2\\]]');
        var valor3 = $('input[name=data\\[valorc3\\]]');
        var tot = (valor + valor1 + valor2);
        var resultContainer = $('#valor_total');
        resultContainer.html(tot.formatMoney(2,',','.'));
        //alert(tot);
    }
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar?

Comment: bem que você poderia postar o código completo e executável, inclusive as bibliotecas usadas,  para que possamos fazer uns testes

Answer (score 0):

Você está indexando os elementos as respectivas variáveis "valores", a forma correta seria:

```js
function calculaSoma(){
        var valor1 = $('input[name=data\\[valorc1\\]]').val();
        var valor2 = $('input[name=data\\[valorc2\\]]').val();
        var valor3 = $('input[name=data\\[valorc3\\]]').val();
        var tot = (valor1 + valor2 + valor3);
        var resultContainer = $('#valor_total');
        resultContainer.html(tot.formatMoney(2,',','.'));
        //alert(tot);
}
```

Comment: Fiz e não deu certo! Mas obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso que você queria fazer?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#valorc1, #valorc2, #valorc3').keyup(function(){   
   var total = 0; 
   var total = parseFloat($('#valorc1').val(), 0);
   $('#valor_total').val(total);
   var valor2 = parseFloat($('#valorc2').val(), 0);
   if (valor2 == 0){
       $('#valor_total').val(total);
   }
   else {
       total += valor2;
       $('#valor_total').val(total);
   }
   var valor3 = parseFloat($('#valorc3').val(), 0);
   if (valor3 == 0){
       $('#valor_total').val(total);
   }
   else{
       total += valor3;
       $('#valor_total').val(total);
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Cirurgia 1<span>*</span></label>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="cirurgia" required data-validation-required-message="Escolha a cirurgia." multiple title="Selecione a Cirurgia">
            <optgroup data-max-options="1">
                <option>Abdominoplastia </option>
                <option>Blefaroplastia </option>
                <option>Dermolipectomia </option>
                <option>Implante Capilar </option>
                <option>Lipoaspiração </option>
                <option>Lipoescultura </option>
                <option>Lifting </option>
                <option>Mastopexia </option>
                <option>Mamoplastia de Aumento </option>
                <option>Mamoplastia Redutora </option>
                <option>Rinoplastia </option>
                <option>Rinoseptoplastia </option>
                <option>Outros </option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <p class="help-block"></p>

<input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorc1" name="data[valorc1]" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o valor." autocomplete="off">


<input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorc2" name="data[valorc1]" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o valor." autocomplete="off" value="0">

<input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorc3" name="data[valorc1]" value="0" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o valor." autocomplete="off">

<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
        <label>Valor Total da Cirurgia<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valor_total" name="data[valor_cirurgia]" readonly="readonly">
        <!-- <p id="valor_total">0,00</p> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seria isso mas não é obrigatório usar os outros inputs. Se o cara colocar somente um valor, no total deveria aparecer, se usar dois, somar os dois.

Comment: @Eduardo basta você verificar na variavel 2 e 3 se as respectivas estão preenchidas se sim passa o valor da mesma, se não passa 0, isso antes de fazer a soma das variáveis

Comment: @Eduardo Editei o post, verifique se agora atende o que você precisa, agora está somando independente de preencher só um, dois ou os três campos.

Comment: Continua calculando somente quando tenho 3 inputs.

Comment: Só pra avisar que sou iniciante em programação, como vocês já devem ter percebido.

Answer (score 0):

Só converte para números.

```
var valor1 = parseFloat($('input[name=data\\[valorc1\\]]'));
var valor2 = parseFloat($('input[name=data\\[valorc2\\]]'));
var valor3 = parseFloat($('input[name=data\\[valorc3\\]]'));
```

Podes usar o parseInt() Também.

Answer (score 0):

Este script ao clicar em uma opção do menu select mostra um input para inserir um valor, um texto clicável  `Mais campos` o qual possibilita adicionar até mais 2 campos. Caso queira adicionar um numero maior de campos basta setar a variável `MaxInputs` para um numero de inputs permitidos.

```js
//script que mostra form quando um option for selecionado
    function showForm(that) {
        if (that.value != "") {
            document.getElementById("meuForm").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("meuForm").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
 //script soma valor dos inputs e mostra resultado na tag span de id="Result"
 $(window).load(function(){

  var $form = $('#meuForm'),
      $sumDisplay = $('#valor_total');  
 
  $form.on('keyup', '.valor', function ()
 
  {
      var $summands = $form.find('.valor');
      var sum = 0;
      $summands.each(function ()
      {
          var value = Number($(this).val());
          if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
      });
  
      $sumDisplay.val(sum);
      
      document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = ": R$" +(sum)+",00"; 
      
  });
 
 //script adiciona input
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var MaxInputs       = 2; //número máximo de inputs
 var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsIncomeWrapper");
 var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreIncomeBox");
 var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
 var FieldCount=1;
  $(AddButton).click(function (e)
  {
          if(x <= MaxInputs)
          {
              FieldCount++;
              $(InputsWrapper).append('\
              <div>\
              <input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorc_'+ FieldCount +'"\
              name="data[valorc1]" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o valor." autocomplete="off"\ />\
              <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remover</a></div>');
              x++;
          }
  return false;
  });
  
 //script retira input e deduz valor correspondente do total
 $("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function (e) {
         if (x > 1) {
             $(this).parent('div').remove();
             x--;
         }
         $('.valor').trigger('keyup');
         return false;
     })
 });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="row control-group">
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
    <label>Cirurgia 1<span>*</span></label>
    <select onchange="showForm(this);" class="form-control selectpicker" id="cirurgia" required data-validation-required-message="Escolha a cirurgia." multiple title="Selecione a Cirurgia">
        <optgroup data-max-options="1">
            <option>Abdominoplastia </option>
            <option>Blefaroplastia </option>
            <option>Dermolipectomia </option>
            <option>Implante Capilar </option>
            <option>Lipoaspiração </option>
            <option>Lipoescultura </option>
            <option>Lifting </option>
            <option>Mastopexia </option>
            <option>Mamoplastia de Aumento </option>
            <option>Mamoplastia Redutora </option>
            <option>Rinoplastia </option>
            <option>Rinoseptoplastia </option>
            <option>Outros </option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <p class="help-block"></p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="meuForm" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorc" name="data[valorc1]" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o valor." autocomplete="off">
<div id="InputsIncomeWrapper"> </div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="row control-group">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
   <input type="text" class="form-control valor2" id="valor_total" name="data[valor_cirurgia]" style="display: none;">
   <a href="#" id="AddMoreIncomeBox">Mais campos</a><br>
   <label>Valor Total da Cirurgia<span id="Result">*</span></label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```